# Problems installing PhoneGap 3.0

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

Every time I try to install PhoneGap 3.0 using a terminal I get the following error message.

```
Last login: Sun Sep 22 13:27:05 on ttys000
ELP-AS-MBP01:~ amartinez$ $ sudo npm install -g phonegap
-bash: $: command not found
```

I've installed Node.js just as the documentation states. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why is there a `$` in front of your command?

Comment: That is what is on phonegap's website.

http://phonegap.com/install/

Comment: The `$` on the web site is a representation of _their prompt_.  Do not type it when you issue the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorials and whatnot prefix commands with a `$` to show that they should be run in a terminal. The `$` itself is the terminal prompt, so you should only copy any text *after* it into your console.

Your console is trying to execute the command `$` which doesn't exist. Your command should be this:

```
sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Comment: Got it!! Thanks for the clarification. I was able to install Phonegap 3.0 :) but I noticed that the xcode project file isn't created? I just see the www, merges, platforms, plugins? Am I missing a step here?

Comment: Never mind, I was able to create the xcode project file. Thanks for the help, its greatly appreciated.